# count page hits that come from emails using query string

Tags: javascript, html, counter

We send follow up emails for inquiries on our products and I wanted to track how effective they are.

This is my plan:

Update the url in the hyperlink of the email to include a query string like:

```
 href=http://www.somepage.htm?source=fromEmail
```

And then track how many visits I get with the query string = fromEmail

My problem is that the page is a .htm and I didn't really want to rewrite it so I'm looking for a javascript counter that can accomodate the query string. Ideally I would like to be able to track the total page hits, as well as the hits that come specifically from these emails. Even more ideally I would like be able to track various information in SQL Server so that the person that requested this could do some reporting on it.

Am I going about this the right way or should I just rewrite it in .net (as we are a .net shop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript on emails is a no-no.  Outlook by default blocks Javascript, so there goes 50% of your users.  Other email systems are not keen on running javascript either.  Remember, when you're doing HTML emails, you need to think 1995-vintage HTML.  Thanks, Microsoft.

You've got a few (ok, but not great) options:

Include an image file on it.  When it gets loaded, count it as a hit.  This is how all the major services handle email tracking, with a 1px X 1px white image file that they most often place at the bottom of the page.  The obvious problem with doing this is that if they use Outlook's preview pane with images enabled, it counts as a hit that they may not have read.  If they read it on Gmail while not unblocking images (set to hidden by default) you've got a real hit that doesn't get recorded.  So, either way, your numbers are wrong.

Track link clicks by routing links through your server.  You use your server to then re-write urls for the browser to follow.  Again, it works well enough, but won't capture the real numbers because only a small percentage of people who get an email actually click a link on them.  [Here's an example using link tagging with Google Analytics](http://cutroni.com/blog/2008/11/04/email-tracking-with-google-analytics/)

A combination of the two above.  It covers both cases, yes, but could result in double counting one user.  You could also hybridize the two by setting a variable on each image that could track back to the source email, then store hits in a DB to eliminate dupes.  That's a LOT of work, though.

My company sends (and tracks) thousands of emails daily as part of its core business, and we always encourage clients to do emails with "teasers" that draw them into other websites for the main content.  Why?  The closer we get a user to the main site, the closer we are to a sale--nobody has ever done an ecommerce transaction solely on email yet (that I know of)  Also, it's one heck of a lot easier and offers far more options to do tracking via Google Analytics on a site than it is to track emails.  Since you can't reliably embed Analytics in emails, your best bet is to get 'em to a website that can.

Comment: I checked out Google Analytics and it is a pretty impressive service they offer. I have no idea how I'm involved in web development and have not heard about it actually.

Answer (score 2):

While it is definitely possible to put some javascript on your .htm page that fires an AJAX request that increments a SQL counter table if the source=fromEmail, I would say that it is more reliable to have the server increment this counter when serving up the page.

Having the server do the work when the hit originally comes in will also allow you to track more specific information about the request for the report.

Comment: Strongly disagree that it's feasible to use JS in emails.  By default, Outlook (and most others) blocks Javascript.  It's possible to unblock, but you just lost half your audience!  http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/top-html-email-coding-mistakes/

Comment: @bpeterson76 : I did not read the question as saying that the javascript was going into the email.  I understand it as a link is in the email, which links to a page that includes the javascript.  No?